# how to make text align middle in jquery slider

Tags: jquery, css

my site is http://daplonline.in/

i got slider jquery form : http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/

i want to display H2 Text in "vertical alignment middle"

my thumbnail image is looking good but i want to make H2 text display middle in 
div

i need top and bottom style or it. my current style is

```
html .image_thumb ul li h2 {
    font-size: 1.4em; 
    margin: 5px 0; padding: 0;
    vertical-align:central;
}
```

but notworking :(

i want to add style for display h2 text middle "TOP and bottom" opp slider's thumbnail.

Comment: Post relevant code. You expect us to dig through your website and find out the problem??

Comment: @Hiral Just Imagine his website as fiddle.... ;)

Comment: @Hiral i updated my question and i want to display h2 font style in  alignment middle from thumb image. please see my first h2 test

Comment: my first h2 text is : Admission cum-Scolarship Test
and 
second is : Mock Test

i want to display thest font style in vertical alignment middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't suggest this solution for long run. But if your content is static then you can go for this quick solution. Apply the following inline style to `<H2>` for 2,3 & 4th.

```
line-height: 40px;

<h2 style="line-height: 40px;">Mock test</h2>
<h2 style="line-height: 40px;">Power Crash Course</h2>
<h2 style="line-height: 40px;">Crash Course</h2>
```

Comment: where to add in my style i have 5 thumb image and 5 h2 near all of them. i want to center from top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can check how to do in this article :

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Example:

```
<div class="block" style="height: 300px;">

    <div class="centered">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
        <p>But he stole up to us again, and suddenly clapping his hand on my shoulder, said&mdash;"Did ye see anything looking like men going towards that ship a while ago?"</p>
    </div>

</div>

/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the text is only a single line and the parent div height has a fixed pixel value you could make the `line-height` the same as the parent container `height`

http://jsfiddle.net/A2HQx/

Comment: it's good but i want to display middle text in top and bottom only 
near the thumb image.

my first h2 text is : Admission cum-Scolarship Test and second is : Mock Test i want to display thest font style in vertical alignment middle

Answer (score 0):

Add following property to respective class:

```
.image_thumb ul li { 
    display: table-cell;
}
.image_thumb img, html .image_thumb ul li h2 { 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```